# I just installed LAMP on a new CentOS 7 server - why are my php-openssl commands undefined?

Tags: php5, openssl, centos7

I have some scripts that utilize some of the openssl PHP functions, such as openssl_opbkdf2.  I am migrating from an Ubuntu server to a newly-created CentOS 7 server with a fresh install of the entire LAMP stack.  Despite hours and hours of googling, I am unable to figure out how to enable these PHP functions.  [Here is a link](http://member-link.com/info.php) that illustrates my problem.  And [here is a link](http://member-link.com/info2.php) that shows my current configuration.

As is plain from the info list, OpenSSL is installed and working.  Every indication I can find leads me to believe these commands should be available.  But they're not!  What am I missing?

Comment: "Oops, this resource could not be found".  Please paste relevant information into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You installed PHP 5.4, but the PHP functions you are trying to use were introduced in PHP 5.5.

[Use the remi and remi-php55 repositories](http://rpms.remirepo.net/) to update your system to PHP 5.5 (or choose a later version).

It should be sufficient to install the appropriate remi-release RPM, enable the `remi` and `remi-php55` repositories, and then `yum update`.

Comment: Ok, that definitely puts me on the right track.  I updated to PHP 5.5.28, and my problem persists.  Is there another module I need to install/enable?

Comment: You do need to restart the web server, so that it is actually _using_ the new PHP version. For instance `systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: ARG!!  I been staring at the screen too long :<   That took care of it - thanks!!